# oracle18c function return table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to recover a bunch of data in the form of a table
I created the type as follows

```
create or replace type Structure_type AS OBJECT
(
SWID Integer,
structure_TYPESid Integer,
MAIN_BRANCHid Integer,
Organizational_structureid Integer,
Administrative_structureid Integer,
structure_tree NVarchar2(1000),
structure_NO NVarchar2(500),
Structure_level Integer
)
```

and create table of type
create or replace type Structure_table_type as table of Structure_type;
Then I created a data retrieval function like the following

```
create or replace function Get_Who_Runs_Stores
(OoA char) return Structure_table_type is
  FunctionResult Structure_table_type;
begin
FunctionResult :=Structure_table_type();
 
 CASE  UPPER(OoA)
 WHEN  'A' then
 FOR x_Structure IN (select b.administrative_tree
    from warehouse w join branches_costcenter b on (w.w_branch=b.swid))
   LOOP
 
 select 
 b.swid  SWID,
 b.costcenter_type_id structure_TYPESid ,
 b.main_branch_id MAIN_BRANCHid,
 b.direct_branch_cost_center_id Organizational_structureid,
 b.direct_adminstration_parent_id Administrative_structureid,
 b.administrative_tree structure_tree,
 b.administrative_no structure_NO,
 b.administrative_level Structure_level
  into FunctionResult
  from branches_costcenter b 

  where 
  x_Structure.Administrative_Tree like  '%-' || b.swid || '-%';
 
 end loop;

  WHEN  'O' then
   
 FOR x_Structure IN (select b.organizationa_tree
    from warehouse w join branches_costcenter b on (w.w_branch=b.swid))
 LOOP
 
 select b.swid  SWID,b.costcenter_type_id structure_TYPESid ,
 b.main_branch_id MAIN_BRANCHid, b.direct_branch_cost_center_id Organizational_structureid,
 b.direct_adminstration_parent_id Administrative_structureid,b.organizationa_tree structure_tree,
 b.organizationa_no structure_NO ,b.organizationa_level Structure_level into FunctionResult
  from branches_costcenter b 
  where 
  x_Structure.Organizationa_Tree like  '%-' || b.swid || '-%';
   
 end loop;
  else 
      return null;
  end case ;
  
return(FunctionResult);
end Get_Who_Runs_Stores;
```

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
Line: 45
Text: from branches_costcenter b

I tried the SQL sentence and it works correctly

```
 select 
 b.swid  SWID,
 b.costcenter_type_id structure_TYPESid ,
 b.main_branch_id MAIN_BRANCHid,
  b.direct_branch_cost_center_id Organizational_structureid,
 b.direct_adminstration_parent_id Administrative_structureid,
 b.administrative_tree structure_tree,
 b.administrative_no structure_NO,
 b.administrative_level Structure_level

  from branches_costcenter b 

  where 
'-1-2-3-12-24-' like  '%-' || b.swid || '-%';
```

How can I get the required data and what is the best way to do so?
Do I have to define all that I want to retrieve data from the function in the form of a table?

Sorry, my English is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will be horrible slow. Apart from that the issue is following: If you run

```
FOR x_Structure IN (select ...) LOOP
   SELECT ...
   INTO FunctionResult
   FROM ...;
END LOOP;
RETURN FunctionResult;
```

then you insert row by row into FunctionResult. At the end you return **only the last row** from your select, all other rows have been overwritten.

Try

```
SELECT ...
BULK COLLECT INTO FunctionResult 
FROM ...;
```

You could also insert row by row, but this is much slower:

```
FOR x_Structure IN (select ...) LOOP
   FunctionResult.Extend();
   SELECT ...
   INTO FunctionResult(FunctionResult.LAST)
   FROM ...;
END LOOP;
```

You cannot select into `FunctionResult` directly. The statement must be like this:

```
SELECT Structure_type(b.swid, b.costcenter_type_id, ..., b.administrative_level) 
BULK COLLECT INTO FunctionResult 
FROM ...
```

**Update**

Depending on your client it might be easier and better to return a RefCursor. Would be like this:

```
create or replace function Get_Who_Runs_Stores(OoA char) return SYS_REFCURSOR is
   res SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
   OPEN res FOR
   SELECT b.swid  SWID,b.costcenter_type_id structure_TYPESid, ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE ...;
   
   RETURN res;
end;
```

You don't have to create any TABLE or OBJECT type, just return the RefCursor.

Comment: thank you 
SELECT Structure_type(b.swid, b.costcenter_type_id, ..., b.administrative_level) 
BULK COLLECT INTO FunctionResult 
FROM ...
It worked fine
But the problem is due to me only as a result of the last query